# How to get the root values of a hierarchical table (postgresql)

Tags: sql, postgresql

Imagine the following hierarchical table:

| ID | Parent ID |
| --- | --- |
| 01 | NULL |
| 02 | NULL |
| 03 | 01 |
| 04 | 02 |
| 05 | 03 |
| 06 | 04 |
| xx | xx |

I want to add the root parent ID for each row as a new field:

| ID | Parent ID | Root Parent ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | NULL |  |
| 02 | NULL |  |
| 03 | 01 | 01 |
| 04 | 02 | 02 |
| 05 | 03 | 01 |
| 06 | 04 | 02 |
| xx | xx | xx |

The total number of subsequent parents my vary, so I can't just join the table with itself x times. Does someone have an idea how to efficiently link those IDs? Thanks a lot in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a recursive `cte`:

```
with recursive cte(id, p) as (
  select t.id, t.id from tbl t where t.parent is null
  union all
  select t1.id, c.p from cte c join tbl t1 on c.id = t1.parent 
)
select t.*, case when t.parent is null then null else c.p end from tbl t join cte c on t.id = c.id
```

[See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=e8744f1988f498c4f3ffff763b930993).